# Why is Clustered Index Scan Number of Executions so high?

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have two similar queries that generate the same query plan, except that one query plan executes a Clustered Index Scan 1316 times, while the other executes it 1 time.

The only difference between the two queries is different date criteria. The long running query actually narrower date criteria, and pulls back less data.

I have identified some indexes that will help with both queries, but I just want to understand why the Clustered Index Scan operator is executing 1316 times on a query that is virtually the same as the one that where it executes 1 time.

I checked the statistics on the PK that is being scanned, and they are relatively up to date.

Original query:

```
select distinct FIR_Incident.IncidentID
from FIR_Incident
left join (
    select incident_id as exported_incident_id
    from postnfirssummary
) exported_incidents on exported_incidents.exported_incident_id = fir_incident.incidentid
where FI_IncidentDate between '2011-06-01 00:00:00.000' and '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000'
    and exported_incidents.exported_incident_id is not null
```

Generates this plan:
[image]

After narrowing the date range criteria:

```
select distinct FIR_Incident.IncidentID
from FIR_Incident
left join (
    select incident_id as exported_incident_id
    from postnfirssummary
) exported_incidents on exported_incidents.exported_incident_id = fir_incident.incidentid
where FI_IncidentDate between '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2011-07-02 00:00:00.000'
    and exported_incidents.exported_incident_id is not null
```

Generates this plan:
[image]

Comment: Could you copy / paste your queries in a code block instead of image files?

Comment: Sure - I added the queries that are generating each plan.

Comment: Which table is the clustered index scan occurring on?

Comment: Clustered Index scan is on the subquery in the left join (PostNFIRSSummary)

Comment: Presumably last time the statistics were updated there was only zero or one row meeting the `FI_IncidentDate between '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2011-07-02 00:00:00.000'` criteria and since then there have been a disproportionate number of inserts in that range. It estimates only 1.07 executions will be needed for that date range. Not the 1,316 that ensue in actuality.

Comment: I agree with Martin, it sounds like a bit of recompiling and stats regen is needed.

Answer (score 10):

The JOIN after the scan gives a clue: with less rows on one side of the last join (reading right to left of course) the optimiser chooses a "nested loop" not a "hash join".

However, before looking at this I'd aim to eliminate the Key Lookup and the DISTINCT.

- Key lookup: your index on FIR_Incident should be covering, probably `(FI_IncidentDate, incidentid)` or the other way around. Or have both and see which is used more often (they both may be)
- The `DISTINCT` is a consequence of the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NOT NULL`. The optimiser has already removed it (the plans have "left semi joins" on the final JOIN) but I'd use EXISTS for clarity

Something like:

```
select 
    F.IncidentID
from 
    FIR_Incident F
where 
    exists (SELECT * FROM postnfirssummary P
           WHERE P.incident_id = F.incidentid)
    AND
    F.FI_IncidentDate between '2011-07-01 00:00:00.000' and '2011-07-02 00:00:00.000'
```

You can also use [plan guides](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916034714/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2009/02/19/plan-guides-plan-freezing-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx) and JOIN hints to make SQL Server use a hash join, but try to make it work normally first: a guide or a hint probably won't stand the test of time because they are only useful for the data and queries you run now, not in the future